# What's the log probability of a Gaussian whose mean is conditioned on another Gaussian?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Define a multi-variate Gaussian as $f(\pmb y|\pmb x)=\mathcal N(\pmb x,.5)$, where $\pmb x$ is a sample from a pre-defined multi-variate Gaussian function $g(\pmb x)=\mathcal N(\pmb \mu, \pmb \Sigma)$. How should I compute the log probability of $\pmb y\sim\mathcal f(\pmb y|\pmb x)$?

I can think of the following answers but I'm not so sure if I take them right

1. For a given $\pmb x$, it's $\log f(\pmb y|\pmb x)$
2. Otherwise, it's $\int \log \mathcal f(\pmb y|\pmb x)+\log g(\pmb x)d\pmb x$

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "the log probability of $\mathbf y\sim f(\mathbf y\mid\mathbf x)$". If we take this literally, the answer would be trivial, since you've specified $f(\mathbf y\mid\mathbf x)$. Also, what do you mean by "for a given $\mathbf x$, it's $\log f(\mathbf y)$; otherwise..."? $f(\mathbf y\mid \mathbf x)$ is by definition "for a given $\mathbf x$". I get the impression that there's some conceptual confusion here. Is it perhaps the logarithm of $f(\mathbf y)$ that you're actually interested in?

Comment: Sorry for that I misuse some mathematical notations. What I tried to express was that if we compute the log probability of $\pmb y$ for a given $\pmb x$, then it's just $\log f(\pmb y|\pmb x)$. If there is no $\pmb x$ is given, then its the otherwise part. I think the otherwise part is the logarithm of $f(\pmb y)$ you mentioned at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m answering the question as clarified in the comments.

$\mathbf y$ is the sum of the two multivariate Gaussian variables with distributions $\mathcal N(\mathbf\mu,\mathbf\Sigma)$, and $\mathcal N(0,0.5)$ (where I presume that by $0.5$ you mean $0.5\cdot\mathbf 1$). The sum of the two multivariate Gaussian variables is again a multivariate Gaussian variable, with mean the sum of the means and variance the sum of the variances (see e.g. [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9879/addition-of-multivariate-gaussians)). So $\mathbf y\sim\mathcal N(\mathbf \mu,\mathbf\Sigma+0.5\cdot\mathbf1)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I can make sense of what you said and you were definitely right. However, it does not seem to be consistent with the otherwise part I said. May I ask where am I wrong? Because my real question actually involves applying another intermediate tanh to x before using it as the mean of the next Gaussian

Comment: @Maybe: I don't know what you're referrring to with "the other part I said".

Comment: Hi, @joriki. That is $\log f(\pmb y)=\int\log f(\pmb y|\pmb x)+\log g(\pmb x)d\pmb x$.

Comment: @Maybe: Ah, I see, sorry, I should have commented on that. That's wrong. It's

$$
f(\mathbf y) = \int f(\mathbf y\mid\mathbf x)g(\mathbf x)\mathrm d\mathbf x\;,
$$

and you can't apply this to the logarithms instead; you'll get a different (and thus wrong) result.

Comment: Hi, @joriki. Is there any way to compute $f(\pmb y)$ without integration if I further apply another itermediate $\tanh$ to $\pmb x$ before using it as the mean of the next Gaussian.

Comment: @Maybe: I doubt it. I don't see one.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Thanks